# If all the conditionals are Gaussians, does it mean the joint is Gaussian?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose I have a set of variables $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and I know that all the conditionals are Gaussian. That is, I know that $p(x_1)$, $p(x_2\mid x_1)$ and $p(x_3 \mid x_2, x_1)$ are Gaussian.

What can we say about the joint distribution $p(x_1, x_2, x_3)$? It is necessarily Gaussian?

## Context

I am reading [Normalizing Flows for Probabilistic Modeling and Inference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.02762). If you go to 3.1.1., in the paragraph below equation (33) we have the following set up:

Suppose I have $\boldsymbol{z}=(z_1, z_2, z_3)$ jointly Gaussian, and I transform this into a random variable $\boldsymbol{z}' = (z_1', z_2', z_3')$ as follows:

- $z_1 ' =  \alpha_1z_1 + \beta_1$ where $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ are **fixed**.
- $z_2' = \alpha_2 z_2 + \beta_2$ where $\{\alpha_2, \beta_2\}$ are output of a neural network with input $\boldsymbol{z}_{< 2} = (z_1)$.
- $z_3' = \alpha_3z_3 + \beta_3$ where $\{\alpha_3, \beta_3\}$ are the output of a neural network with input $\boldsymbol{z}_{<3} = (z_1, z_2)$

Then we know:

- $z_1$ is Gaussian since it's a marginal of a Gaussian.
- $z_1'$ is Gaussian since it's an affine transformation of a Gaussian.

Then, they say, this means that all the conditionals $z_i'\mid \boldsymbol{z}_{< i}'$ are Gaussian however the joint $\boldsymbol{z}'$ is not.

Comment: Consider the simpler question with just two variables.  For instance, suppose the distribution of $x_2$ given $x_1$ is standard Gaussian when $x_1\lt 0$ and otherwise is Gaussian with mean $10$ and unit variance: is $(x_1,x_2)$ jointly Gaussian?

Comment: What if $X_1 \equiv X_2 \equiv X_3 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1)?$ Clearly, marginals are normal. Do you consider the joint distribution to be multivariate normal?

Comment: @whuber thank you! I added an example with code, but would you be able to show me some maths?

Comment: @BruceET I would think so? I'm honestly so confused hahaha I thought they would be jointly gaussian with identity matrix as the covariance matrix?

Comment: Example in Q does not have normal $X_2$ marginal.

Comment: The problem with your situation is that $p(x_1 \vert x_2)$ can mean many things. You have a counter example now. But maybe you were more specifically thinking about a different conditional distribution? E.g. when $p(x_1 \vert x_2) \sim N(a+b x_2, \sigma^2)$ then the joint distribution is a multivariate Gaussian.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus you're right I need to give more context. I'll update my question.

Comment: @BruceET $X_2$ is not required to be normal marginal, it's only required to be normal conditional on $X_1$, which it is in whuber's example

Comment: The latest edit has changed the substance of the question, because now we've added the assumption that the relationship between all the variables is linear, so @whuber's counterexample no longer applies

Comment: @JakeWestfall It's not linear! The parameters depend on the previous dimensions! Basically only $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ are constants. Instead $\alpha_2 = \alpha_2(z_1)$ and $\beta_2 = \beta_2(z_1)$

Comment: You're right @Euler_Salter, I misread the new text. What's linear is the relationships between $z_i$ and $z'_i$; the relationships among the $z'_i$ need not be linear

Comment: @JakeWestfall do you know if then the joint is going to be gaussian again?

Comment: @Euler_Salter could you explain, 'output of a neural network'. Are these $\beta$ and $\alfa$ the same for all $z$, in which case it is just a regular (uniform) linear transformation, or does the transformation depend on $z$.

Comment: To reiterate, even in the simplest case where the neural net is single layered, where say $\alpha_2 = 1\{w_{\alpha_2}z_1^' + b_{\alpha_2} >0\}$ for example it should be clear that $z_2^'$ is not marginally gaussian and the joint f(z_1^',z_2^') is thus not gaussian either. For arbitrary neural nets there is no case that you get joint gaussian. Even if the activation function is affine and single layered, then $z_2^' = (w_1z_1^')z_2^' + b. And the first term is the product of gaussians and not gaussian either.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus If you're referring to my comment to BruceET, my point is that his objection does not invalidate whuber's counterexample to the general question as written. The fact that whuber's example does not lead to all normal marginals is not a problem because the question does not suppose that all the marginals are normal. In fact, it's simply another way of recognizing the validity of the counterexample: it satisfies the premises of the question (as written above **Context**), but it doesn't even lead to normal marginals, and so clearly doesn't lead to a multivariate normal

Comment: I see -- it is definitely possible that I misinterpreted what Bruce was trying to say with his comment. If that's the case, then sorry @BruceET !

Comment: @JakeWestfall. No problem. And maybe my comment could have been clearer with another sentence explicitly stating its intent.

Answer (score 4):

> This answer is partial, and based on Whuber's comment: Consider the simpler question with just two variables. For instance, suppose the distribution of $x_2$ given $x_1$ is standard Gaussian when $x_1 < 0$ and otherwise is Gaussian with mean 10 and unit variance: is $(x_1, x_2)$ jointly Gaussian?

This is how I generated the two random variables.

```
x1 <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=0, sd=1)
x2 <- rep(0, 1000)
for (i in 1:1000){
  if (x1[i] < 0){
    x2[i] = rnorm(n=1)
  } else {
    x2[i] = rnorm(n=1, mean=10)
  }
}
```

And this is how I plot them

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2)
ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x1, y=x2))
```

Obtaining the following figure:

[image]

which looks quite different from a **bivariate Normal distribution**.

Comment: This reflects *a* joint distribution--but it's obviously not bivariate Normal.  (Using simulation and graphics in this way is very effective and obviates any need for a mathematical demonstration, I hope!)

Comment: @Westfall I’ve just included it!